# memory.limit() confusion: "memory.limit() is not longer supported"

Tags: memory

When I write "memory.limit()" I get the following <strike>bug</strike> message:

> memory.limit()
> [1] Inf
> Warning message:
> 'memory.limit()' is no longer supported

What I need is to increasing the memory size...
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems this isn't a bug. When reading the documentation provided with the Version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22), it says:

- R on Windows now uses the system memory allocator. Doug Lea's allocator was used since R 1.2.0 to mitigate performance limitations seen with system allocators on earlier versions of Windows.
- memory.limit() and memory.size() are now stubs on Windows (as on Unix-alikes).

So, I've been told, this means it's just no longer supported...

Comment: Is there any alternative? The computer completely freezes where it is necessary to turn off the power. Can't limit RAM for R?