# "memory.limit() is no longer supported" - work around?

Tags: r, macos, memory

I am trying to increase memory in Rstudio. Previously, I used `memory.limit()`, but I am now getting the warning message that this is no longer supported. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72188858/memory-limit-bug-memory-limit-is-not-longer-supported-increasing-memory), `memory.limit()` and `memory.size()` are now "stubs on Windows (as on Unix-alikes)." Two questions:

1. What does "are now on stubs" mean?
2. What alternative do I have for increasing the memory limit?

Comment: What have you tried exactly? Both `memory.limit()` and `memory.size()` still work for me on the latest version of RStudio `2022.07.1 Build 554` .

Comment: @OliverHennhoefer on Mac, the doc says `Report on Memory Allocation (no longer supported)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the [workflow](https://bioinfocore.com/unix/r-set-memory-limit-on-mac-for-rstudio/) on Mac/Unix differs to non-Windows platforms:

1. (Open the terminal)
2. Open the `.Renviron` file
3. Add/Change the parameter `R_MAX_VSIZE=100Gb`

This seems to be also discussed in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51295402/r-on-macos-error-vector-memory-exhausted-limit-reached)

Looks like the whole process can be done through R as well:

```
library(usethis) 
usethis::edit_r_environ()
```