memory.limit() is no longer supported in R?
I got an error message "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 34.3 Gb" when I tried to create a large vector in R.
Then I tried to use memory.limit() to increase the memory size, however I got another error message "'memory.limit()' is no longer supported ". Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Windoze? I think it was a way to deal with aspects of memory management in Windows. Searching produces some relevant documentation https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html#:~:text=Under%20most%2064%2Dbit%20versions,by%20the%20OS)%20is%208Tb.

“ The limit for a 64-bit build of R (imposed by the [Windoze] OS) is 8Tb.”

Possible duplicate question. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73776480/memory-limit-is-no-longer-supported-work-around and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75504216/warning-message-memory-size-is-no-longer-supported
